# How did Docker generate container names in the past?

Tags: docker, github, random, generator

### Container Name Generator

According to [names-generator.go](https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/88241b99893cce78a7734a19b38d468d0dcb6156/pkg/namesgenerator/names-generator.go#L120-L121) :

> Docker, starting from 0.7.x, generates names from notable scientists and hackers.

### History

The commit history of this file only goes back to 2013:

[image: docker git commits]

### Questions

1. What did docker use prior to `0.7.x`? Animal names?
2. Is that list (or older docker source code) available somewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the GitHub UI, click "History" at the top-right corner of that file's page.  That takes you to a listing of all commits that have ever touched this file.  There aren't actually that many; the oldest, which you cite in the question, is [commit a009d4a](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#volume-mode).  Click on its commit hash in the UI.

That takes you to [a page that shows that commit](https://github.com/moby/moby/commit/a009d4ae8d67b40c0109865f4d83e6e294931ce7#diff-a461eecf31e5c471572678b08330893a).  That commit is mostly a pair of file renames.  Note what got renamed.

That also commit has `1 parent 3fc9de3`.  Click on that commit hash, and then the "Browse Files" button at the top-right corner of the UI.  You are now [browsing the Docker source tree](https://github.com/moby/moby/tree/3fc9de3d0396d15f7310910a86100257853cdd90) at the commit immediately before the rename.

The commit description and diff reference a package `namesgenerator` that got renamed.  You can find that in the top-level directory listing in the pre-rename commit.  Click into that, and then click "History" on that page to find [the very early history of the name generator](https://github.com/moby/moby/commits/3fc9de3d0396d15f7310910a86100257853cdd90/namesgenerator).

From this history we can find out:

- The name generator didn't exist at all more than 2 months before the rename commit you cite; [its first commit](https://github.com/moby/moby/commit/0d2924408bad7aa797bfaf0610e836d82928296f#diff-64375ab1eaf4cb4a664d73c31b5132d8) was on 28 October 2013.
- The very first version of it generated names of the form `color_animal`.  Its [second commit](https://github.com/moby/moby/commit/a51fb4dd35b2324ff4f1f772202d45a944b9d5e1#diff-64375ab1eaf4cb4a664d73c31b5132d8) added more colors and animals, so it would allow names like `brown_bear`, `red_bird`, `yellow_duck`, and so on.
- The `mood_inventor` scheme was introduced in [the fourth commit](https://github.com/moby/moby/commit/5d6ef3177b57371c2dd9b9e4253fbc326d072554#diff-64375ab1eaf4cb4a664d73c31b5132d8) on 23 November 2013.
- These pairs were [required](https://github.com/moby/moby/commit/07180f3aa75377b4c3227da006df00ec4f032589#diff-64375ab1eaf4cb4a664d73c31b5132d8) to have cool inventor names, be easy to remember, be mildly funny on occasion, and be politically correct, though the heuristics for determining these were rather limited (all four conditions were fixed to `true`).  These requirements were [removed](https://github.com/moby/moby/commit/ccaea227e0e9356ab293610784b635c643e9a15e#diff-fc472e36b51ee5440e59495eb3841faa) in 2016 (since the test actually did nothing).

Looking at the [Docker `CHANGELOG.md`](https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md), Docker 0.6.5 added the initial "Containers can now be named" with the first `color_animal` scheme, 0.6.6 "Add[ed] some more colors and animals to increase the pool of generated names", and 0.7.0 added "Container naming: organize your containers by giving them memorable names" with the modern scheme.

Comment: Thank you for a great answer to an obscure question! :)